# Spring Boot Configuration. Collection Autowiring - Getting unexpected value after successful autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have `@Configuration` class in *Spring Boot Application*.

It contains `String`, `Map<Integer, List<String>>` and `List<String>` bean types.

```
@Bean
public String getSomeString() {
    return "String";
}

@Bean
public Map<Integer, List<String>> getMap() {
    return ...;
}

@Bean
public List<String> getList() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    return list;
}

@Bean
public CustomClass getInstance(Map<Integer, List<String>> map, String someString, List<String> list) {
    return new CustomClass(map, someString, list);
}
```

From `getList()` I return list which contains `"1","2"`.
But In `getInstance()` I get list which contains only one element - `"String"`. The same as the value of `getSomeString()`.

When I change `List<String> getList()` to `ArrayList<String> getList()`(and in parameters of `getInstance()` too) It works.

Where is the problem?

**p.s.**
I don't have other methods which return `List<String>`
I don't have other config files

Comment: can you provide some more data, it's not clear try creating beans with different names

Comment: What can I add more? I've tried to name @Bean("list") but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior defined by [spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation), as per documentation:

> You can also provide all beans of a particular type from the
>   ApplicationContext by adding the annotation to a field or method that
>   expects an array of that type, as the following example shows:
>
> ```
> public class MovieRecommender {
>
>     @Autowired
>     private MovieCatalog[] movieCatalogs;
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> The same applies for typed collections, as the following example shows:
>
> ```
> public class MovieRecommender {
>
>     private Set<MovieCatalog> movieCatalogs;
>
>     @Autowired
>     public void setMovieCatalogs(Set<MovieCatalog> movieCatalogs) {
>         this.movieCatalogs = movieCatalogs;
>     }
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```

This means, when you use a collection/array in conjunction with autowiring, spring will check if it can gather all beans assignable to your generic type and create a collection/array for you. In above example it gather all `MovieCatalog` beans, in your case it gather all `String` beans.

For instance, if you modify your list parameter to `List<Object>`, you will receive all objects in the ApplicationContext.

**Solution**

I would suggest you to resolve it by using `@Qualifier`.

You can use `@Qualifier` to indicate the bean you want to inject to your method:

```
@Bean
  public Object getInstance(Map<Integer, List<String>> map, String someString, @Qualifier("getList")List<String> list) {
...
}
```

You can also define a name for the bean and use it on `@Qualifier`:

```
 @Bean(name = "list")
  public List<String> getList() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    return list;
  }

  @Bean
  public Object getInstance(Map<Integer, List<String>> map, String someString, @Qualifier("list")List<String> list) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Early I used @Bean("name") and the same field name in parameters. But now It doesn't work without @Qualifier